# crystal reports not working in shared server

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, configuration, shared-hosting, crystal-reports-2008

i am trying to host my website in shared server. 
but the shared server not having crystal reports run time environment in the server.

my question:
is there any alternate solution to solve that issue?

Comment: I don't believe so. If you want to actually run the reports via their web portal on that machine - it's going to need the runtime. You could optionally collect parameter information on the web server and then pass that data to _another_ server, and generate a PDF and send that back to the user.

Comment: Hmm.... If you want to run CR on the server, it's always need the runtime. Or it wont work. Could you please kindly ask your provider to check it again? Or you may try other hosting provider that support CR.